# Will removing a 2nd log file break log shipping?

Tags: sql-server-2005, transaction-log, log-shipping

We have a large database 200GB+ to which we added a second log file to cater for growth during an upgrade. This is now no longer needed so we want to remove it. Normally this would be a simple `ALTER DATABASE <blah> REMOVE FILE <filename>` statement.

However our database is log shipped to a secondary for reporting, so the question is - will removing this file break log shipping?

Server is SQL Server 2005 SP3 Standard Edition if it has any bearing.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the extra file won't give you any problems.

Answer (score 0):

You are shipping backups of logs, not the actual ldf files. Since the backup mechanism would punt if the restore targets were different, I think you have a risk and would probably need to reinit log shipping. [Found these notes.](http://ramaudaya.blogspot.com/2011/09/adding-additional-datafile-to-primary.html) You'd have to halt shipping and manually apply the tran log WITH MOVE to avoid a likely reinit otherwise.

As for a possible work-around, you could empty log contents into other files, and then shrink the log to the smallest possible size. That should work but you'd have a tiny lingering file. Make sure to checkpoint/backup before you try.

Comment: Hi Eric, Thanks for the response, thought there might be a risk, so given it's a Friday, I'll go for the work-around for the moment until I can do some proper testing.

Comment: Good plan :) Have a good weekend